# Editar celdas de Excel con Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, excel

Intento hacer un programa para leer y escribir celdas de un archivo Excel y estoy siguiendo un pequeño tutorial que he encontrado.
El caso es que en el momento de agregar las referencias;

```
microsoft.visualstudio.tools.applications.runtime
microsoft.office.interop.excel
```

No las encuentro por ningun lado, acabo de instalar Office y en la instalacion e seleccionado para instalar el paquete `.NET Programmability Support` pero no veo las *.dll por ningun lado...

¿Que librerias debo utilizar para trabajar con Excel?

Comment: Esas referencias están en la pestaña `COM` de la ventana Agregar referencias. Imagino que la estas buscando en la de librerias de .NET

Comment: Si has instalado Office las tendrás en la carpeta donde se instala, en mi caso es C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\DCF\

Comment: has una busqueda por *interop*.* en tu PC, te la tiene que encontrar.

Comment: Gracias, las encontre en C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\DCF\ , me queda la duda de porque no las encontraba ni en la pestaña COM, ni en las .NET...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes trabajar con Excel, generando ficheros y manipulando los ya existentes, con la librería [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)

Utilizando estas librerías tienes la ventaja de que no dependes de tener una instalación de Excel en la máquina en que desarrolles o mejor aún, en la que debas tener el código en producción.

```
var libro = new XLWorkbook();
var hoja = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Hoja 1");
hoja.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Hola, mundo!";
libro.SaveAs("c:\\temp\\excel.xlsx");
```

Puedes encontrar un buen artículo [aquí](https://www.variablenotfound.com/2013/03/generar-archivos-excel-como-un-senor.html) (de donde he adaptado el código) y [aquí](https://www.fixedbuffer.com/index.php/2018/09/11/generacion-de-ficheros-excel-con-closedxml/)

Esta librería además tiene la ventaja de que puedes instalarla desde el gestor de paquetes NuGet.